# ODBC connet cache database, call an stored procedure with parameters,no data return

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, odbc, intersystems-cache

Using ODBC to connet cache database, call an stored procedure with parameters,no data return,but no problem in the DBeaver(or any other tools) with same procedure.
I'm sure connection string is right,other code is right too,but OdbcDataReader return null.
Here is my code:

```
string sql;
sql= "CALL web_DHCSTM_JXGL.PublicHealth_VPatHospitalNEW('0008787','','')";
OdbcCommand com = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);
OdbcDataReader dr3 = com.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

I'm using .net framework 4.0 MVC.
There is a similar procedure I call it with the same approach,and that one works,and both of them works on the DBeaver,so wired...

Answer (score 0):

### If your connection is successful and your procedure exists in the DB. you may use these lines to Execute the SP

```
OdbcCommand ODBCCommand = new OdbcCommand("{CALL web_DHCSTM_JXGL.PublicHealth_VPatHospitalNEW('0008787','',''}", 
ODBCConnection);
ODBCCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
ODBCCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Anyparam", Arslan_aslam);// if SP wants any parameters.DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();
OdbcDataAdapter ODBCDatadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(ODBCCommand);
ODBCDatadapter.Fill(DataTable); // Datatable will be populated in the response of SP
ODBCDatadapter.Dispose();
```

Comment: I have tried it,this way didn't work.actually there is a similar SP I call it with the same  approach(my approach),and it works,but it didn't work on this SP,so wired...

Comment: have you executed your SP using Call on Database query panel?

Comment: Yeah,using the DBeaver,got data return normally